# Nexmo PHP lib master Receipt

Tags: php, vonage

I am using the nexmo api for send text message.all the function work just fine except the Receipt function it a bool function but till now i dont know how to use it?

this is the link of the lib https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on that specific library, but if you set the `status-report-req` parameter to `1` when [sending a message](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/send-message), you'll [get a delivery receipt](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/handle-delivery-receipt) when the message is delivered, is queued, etc.

A quick look at the library seems to show that it supports creating a receipt object from an inbound request.